# Not able to dynamically install prebuilt native-addon as npm dependency based on process.platform and architecture

Tags: npm-install, node-gyp, npm-package, prebuild, node-native-addon

I'm developing npm package (`my_package`) that is using domain-specific C/C++ libraries (`c-library`) via Node-API. Such setup has a reason, because this C/C++ library is being well maintained and rewriting it in JS/TS would not be feasible.

The problem I'm currently facing is: how do I distribute prebuilt modules of that library?

Normally I would make use of `node-gyp`, but another constraint I'm having is that my npm package will be distributed via third-party platform, which installs additional modules/plugins by exec'ing `npm install <my_package>` (and later using some magic to load them as UI and functionality addons). It is not guaranteed that `node-gyp` is available on this third-party platform, or maybe some of their dependencies are missing (like python3) since there are different docker images of this "platform" with different builds and tools available.

Furthermore, building C/C++ library could take substantial amount of time on small VPS (where the platform is hosted), and as I would like installation process to be as straightforward as possible, I would like to avoid users having to spend their time here.
The binary itself is pretty big (15-20MB) and including all prebuilt binaries for all architectures into `my_package` would also not be a good solution IMO.

Bottom line is: my npm package loads binary lib and it is being installed by running `npm install <my_package>`, and I cannot influence that. I also cannot influence environment in which my package is installed therefore I cannot rely on `node-gyp`. How do I deliver pre-compiled binary modules of the library to run on: `linux-x64-glibc`, `linux-x64-musl`, `linux-arm64-glibc`, `linux-arm64-musl`, `darwin-x64`, `darwin-arm64`?

I thought of different options:

1. Publish arch-specific packages of `my_package` (i.e. `my_package-linux-x64-glibc`, `my_package-arm64-musl` etc). Include "hard-coded" arch-specific dependency to `c-library` into `package.json` of `my_package`.

```
package.json (of `my_package-linux-x64-glibc`)
{

...
dependencies: {
    `c-library-linux-x64-glibc`: "*"
}
...
}
```

I do not like it, because it makes installation process more complicated for the user: they need to be aware where their platform is hosted and install exact "variation" of `my_package` that will run there. Kind of complicated.

2. Publish `my_package` as one "generic" package. Include arch-specific dependency to `c-library` in `package.json` based on some conditioning which will be checked when `npm install my_package` is executed.

User would not have to deal with all these process/architecture things, but rather simply install one "facade" `my_package`, that evaluates environment at runtime and pulls in prebuilt `c-library` (for example `c-library-linux-x64-musl`) depending on conditions.

```
package.json (of `my_package`)
{
...
dependencies: {
    'linux-x64': {
        `c-library-linux-x64-glibc`: "*"
    }
}
...
}
```

Problem: I'm not able to include dependencies that are based on conditions in `package.json` of my_package.

3. Publish `my_package` as one "generic" package. Use `postinstall.js` lifecycle script to do runtime evaluation of environment and then exec `"npm install c-library-" + process.platform + "-"  + process.arch"` to fetch proper prebuilds.

This was a breakthrough idea, but apparently, because `npm install c-library-...` is executed from within the `npm install my_package` command's "scope", it is removing all the dependencies of `my_package`. Due to the fact that `npm install my_package` is updating `package-lock.json` file **after** postinstall scripts have been executed. Postinstall is run on line 95, dependencies are saved/added starting from line 110:

```
95 info run my_package@0.0.1 postinstall node_modules/my_package node postinstall.js install
96 info run my_package@0.0.1 postinstall { code: 0, signal: null }
97 timing build:run:postinstall:node_modules/my_package Completed in 61ms
98 timing build:run:postinstall Completed in 61ms
99 timing build:deps Completed in 63ms
100 timing build Completed in 63ms
101 timing reify:build Completed in 63ms
102 timing reify:trash Completed in 0ms
103 timing reify:save Completed in 3ms
104 http fetch POST 200 http://0.0.0.0:4873/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 464ms
105 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 468ms
106 silly audit report {}
107 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
108 timing reify:audit Completed in 470ms
109 timing reify Completed in 2007ms
110 silly ADD node_modules/ms
111 silly ADD node_modules/typedi
```

4. Use `node-pre-gyp` that would try to find prebuilt version of `c-library` somewhere in aws s3, if it is not found - fallback to compilation in `node-gyp` way.

I have not tried that, and I'm a bit sceptical here because of different platforms/architectures and libc variants that need to be supported. I would also need to include source code of `c-library` as git submodule of `my_package` which is maybe not the best way to organise components.
Additionally, it [does not look](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/685#issuecomment-1614565952) that `node-pre-gyp` is being regularly maintained.

I would appreciate if someone could share their idea on the above and perhaps open my eyes on some other option that I have not still discovered.